# How to store collections in database?

Tags: mysql, database, hana

How to store a collection in database??

```
/**
    * POJO class to hold Employee info.
 *
 * @author i539991 - Priyanka Taneja
 */
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
@Jacksonized
public class Employee
{
    /** The identifier column. */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Integer id;

    /** The first name. */
    @Column(name = "EMP_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String empName;

    @Column
    private List<String> employeeAddress;


    /** The credit card number. */
    @Column(name = "CREDIT_CARD_NUM", nullable = false)
    private String creditCardNumber;

    /** The account number. */
    @Column(name = "ACCOUNT_NUMBER", nullable = false)
    private String accountNumber;
}


CREATE COLUMN TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
ID INTEGER CS_INT NOT NULL ,
EMP_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
ACCOUNT_NUMBER VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
CREDIT_CARD_NUM VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
TENANT_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

What will be the datatype for List in SQL query?

How can i store List in database?? For example how can i store employeeAddress in List of String in Employee table in database.

Comment: Why collection? Does an employee may have more than one address? Serialize your collection (for example to JSON) then store. Or create separate table for addresses and use FK for relation.

Comment: My Employee can have multiple addresses.

Comment: Use relational structures for relational data: create separate table and store all the addresses in it

Answer (score 0):

You can use ARRAY to list the values.

Assuming you want to add ADDRESS Column declare it as an Array , you can create like below:

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
ID INTEGER CS_INT NOT NULL ,
EMP_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
ACCOUNT_NUMBER VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
CREDIT_CARD_NUM VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
TENANT_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
ADDRESS NVARCHAR(200) ARRAY,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Insert values into table using ARRAY below:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE ( ID, EMP_NAME,ADDRESS) VALUES ( 1,'XXX',ARRAY('FLATNO: 999','STREET NO: 333','CITY','PINCODE'));
```

Result of select will be below :

[image]